# Resize image withour squash or strech with php?

Tags: php

In a folder i have my main images ,i need some code in php that read all images from folder and resize it without squash or strech with php  and put the resized images in a destination folder.

Thanks

Comment: if you mean resize to the width and height you want without any changes, just forget .. the best you get is mantaining the aspect radio by resizing relativelly to width or height, (almost) never both ...

Comment: but how some sites resize thier images as a fixed size and it is good like huffingtonpost.com they have some small size 74x58 please see.

Answer (score 2):

Open your image with [ImageCreateFromJPEG](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php), create a new empty image with [ImageCreateTrueColor](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) and copy the content with [ImageCopyResampled](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) from the original image to the new image. You can save it then with [imageJPEG](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php). Like this:

```
<?php
$imageInfo   = getImageSize( 'image.jpg' );
$imageWidth  = $imageInfo[0];
$imageHeight = $imageInfo[1];
$thumbWidth  = round( $imageWidth / 2 );
$thumbHeight = round( $imageHeight / 2 );

$gdImage = imageCreateFromJPEG( 'image.jpg' );
$gdThumb = imageCreateTrueColor( $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight ); // thumbnail size here

imageCopyResampled( $gdThumb, $gdImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight );
imageJPEG( $gdThumb, 'image_thumb.jpg', 80 );

imageDestroy( $gdImage );
imageDestroy( $gdThumb );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks,but first i must read from maif folder then write to destination folder, i like that this process be in one script so if i have 500 images in the folder then with executing the codes in destination folder i have 500 resized,if you write this part of code i appreciate.

Comment: The problem with doing that many files with one execution is php's maximum execution time which is set to 30s (?) by default. So you won't be able to create all images in one run that way. A good way to solve this is to only do like 5 or 10 files per run and have the script run multiple times (or for example with a cronjob).

You can read the files out of one directory using the `readdir` function (see the examples in the manual). I suggest you to create some database or text file first where you store the names of the files and update that one with each run of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Resize both width and height by a percent:

newwidth = width * percent%

newheight = height * percent%

If you need a given width newwidth for example, then calculate the percent of newwidth/width*100, and calculate the height based on the resulting percent, as above.